# package.json entry points with rollup and @rollup/plugin-node-resolve

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, rollup, snowpack, rxdb

I'm looking for some help with package.json entry points (i.e. with [`@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve), with snowpack).  For a package I'm importing (indirectly via RxDB), I'm having some issues and according to its maintainer, it's just not choosing the correct entry point:

> the broadcast-channel module is a esm module that has a different export index for browsers. You bundler should not include the methods/node.js file with the promisify call

The entry point in question:

[https://github.com/pubkey/broadcast-channel/blob/master/package.json#L11](https://github.com/pubkey/broadcast-channel/blob/56e9be9469d9419ac835bf7278aea353acfd99aa/package.json#L11)

The exports section from `package.json`^ looks like this -- my understanding is that if I can get rollup to choose the entries under `"browser"` then that would solve my problem:

```
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "node": {
        "import": "./dist/esnode/index.js",
        "default": "./dist/es5node/index.js"
      },
      "browser": {
        "import": "./dist/esbrowser/index.js",
        "default": "./dist/lib/index.es5.js"
      }
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
```

I've tried the following options but it has not helped:

```
nodeResolve({
    browser: true,
    mainFields: ['browser'],
    exportConditions: ['browser'],
})
```

Can anyone recommend some alternative config options to try?

Additional info, in case it helps: the same issue comes up when I use `@snowpack/plugin-webpack`